# Map Fragment do not show Map details Android

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, google-api, maps

I'm trying to implement the maps fragment in my application, but when I test the apps on the simulator, the map details do not show up(unlike other devices/emulators).
I'm using the Pixel 3 API 29 emulator to test the app

(build.gradle)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.G26.fitnessandnutritionbuddy"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

(Here is an image of the issue)

[image]

I expected to see the details of the maps (this happens in a few devices), but in general, most devices that are used for testing the app have the same issue.